# I keep on getting an error of: Division by zero (php)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to calculate the 24 hour price change and I have here with me the codes and its formula but I keep getting division by zero error, please help? thanks!

here's my code:

```
       <?php
          $differ = ($get_price['price'] - $get_data['open']) / $get_data['open'] * 100;
          if($differ != 0){
          $hour_change = number_format((float)$differ, 2,'.','');
          }else{
          $hour_change = 0;
          }
       ?>
```

Comment: `var_dump($get_data);` and what do you get?

Comment: Yes, and it returned this: string(8) "10378.05" @Jonnix but I don't get it why it throws an error of division by zero sometimes...is there something wrong in my codes?

Comment: So it's a string not an array? O_o

Comment: what do I have to do with this? can you help me, I'm not really good on this one. @Jonnix

Comment: Really, I don't know. `$get_data` is apparently a string, so doesn't contain `open` key. You'll need to find out why that variable isn't what you were expecting it to be, which isn't something we can do for you.

Comment: Okay will do, and thank you for your help. @Jonnix

Comment: You could try just using `$get_data`, removing the `['open']` bit, but whether that's correct (i.e. whether that's the right thing to do, not whether it will make it work) you'd have to check.

Comment: Okay noted, thanks! @Jonnix

Comment: already got it!

Answer (score 0):

Considering the comments under your question, $get_data is just a string, not an array.

I recommend you to check whoever is setting $get_data.

Comment: What was the solution?